# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 -- how to guard against invalid user input?

Tags: python, validation, user-input

I made a program where the user enters a number, and the program would count up to that number and display how much time it took. However, whenever I enter letters or decimals (i.e. 0.5), I would get a error. Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop\test6.py", line 5, in <module>
    z = int(z)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'df'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Here is the full code:

```
import time
x = 0
print("This program will count up to a number you choose.")
z = input("Enter a number.\n")
z = int(z)
start_time = time.time()
while x < z:
    x = x + 1
    print(x)
end_time = time.time()
diff = end_time - start_time
print("That took",(diff),"seconds.")
```

Please help!

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What should `z` contain in the input is "df" or "0.5" instead of a number?

Answer (score 8):

Well, there really a way to 'fix' this, it is behaving as expected -- you can't case a letter to an int, that doesn't really make sense. Your best bet (and this is a pythonic way of doing things), is to simply write a function with a try... except block:

```
def get_user_number():
    i = input("Enter a number.\n")
    try:
        # This will return the equivalent of calling 'int' directly, but it
        # will also allow for floats.
        return int(float(i)) 
    except ValueError:
        #Tell the user that something went wrong
        print("I didn't recognize {0} as a number".format(i))
        #recursion until you get a real number
        return get_user_number()
```

You would then replace these lines:

```
z = input("Enter a number.\n")
z = int(z)
```

with

```
z = get_user_number()
```

Comment: Why call itself recursively upon failure?  That's hideously inefficient.

Comment: @Jeff While Python is not optimized for tail recursion, there has to be at least some trust for the user -- we need to assume that by the second or third time they've been told that they've screwed up, they would get the message. Looking at it, I suppose I could put it in a `while True:` but to me this reads as more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking

```
if string.isdigit(z):
```

And then executing the rest of the code if it is a digit.

Because you count up in intervals of one, staying with int() should be good, as you don't need a decimal.

EDIT: If you'd like to catch an exception instead as wooble suggests below, here's the code for that:

```
try: 
    int(z)
    do something
except ValueError:
    do something else
```

Comment: It's more pythonic to just catch the exception.

Comment: Also, if you can, you should wait to `do something` till after the `try except` block. That way you're less likely to catch some unrelated error.

Comment: string.isdigit is not Python 3.x compatible

Comment: `z.isdigit()` is Python3 ok. @Wooble not necessarily, don't be dogmatic. What's easier to do in the case - i think 1-line check beats 2-3 line try/catch